# How to create a lookup in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, lookup

I have a data frame in R that examines the ELO rating of college football teams over the course of several decades.

[Data Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGSkx.jpg)

Each row is a specific game, and the team listed under the Team.A column is a winning team while the team under Team.B is a losing team. Also, the ELO scores under Elo.A represent the score for Team.A and the ELO scores under Elo.B represent the score for Team.B for those games, respectively.

I want to create a time-series that, for instance, looks at all of the ELO scores in Elo.A and Elo.B for Minnesota. Is there a way in R that can pull the date and scores in both of those columns for that one school?

Comment: Please do not provide images of data. Use `head` or `dput` or just plain text, so users can copy/paste it when preparing answers.

Comment: To expand on @neilfws's comment. Some reasons (against images) are slightly less obvious but still important, including: it breaks screen readers *hard*; search engines don't read them, so searches will not find it; mobile device screen size might be a limiting factor. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272

Comment: What do you mean by "looks for".  What do you want the output to look like? Be exact. Give us an example.

Comment: @DeNovo This is the output that I am looking to create for a school such as Minnesota - a column that lists all of the dates and elo scores from elo.A and elo.B for that school.

Comment: Please provide an example of the object you're looking to get as output in your question. And please fix your example data, as mentioned in the first two comments.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
df[df$team.A=="Minesota" | df$tema.B=="Minesota", ]
```

And you can select and specific columns using c(...) in the space after the ','

Comment: using dplyr  `dplyr::filter(df, teamA %in% "Minesotsa" | teamB %in% "Minesota)`

Comment: Yeah, that also looks nicer imho. I'm pretty new to dplyr, but it's very nice :) Isn't it %in% with 2 '%' though?

Comment: yeah I just edited while you were writting, also forgot a " at the end and the obvious  dyslexia with Minesota